# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jButton2ActionPerformed, access$1200, actionPerformed

Tags: java, exception

I would appreciate your help with this situation I never had before. Yesterday everything was working perfectly with my program, but today, as I am pressing `JButton` in my program, I am getting `Exception` :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mvap/optionsSearchWindow$optionsSearch
    at mvap.optionsSearchWindow.jButton2ActionPerformed(optionsSearchWindow.java:9124)
    at mvap.optionsSearchWindow.access$1200(optionsSearchWindow.java:22)
    at mvap.optionsSearchWindow$2.actionPerformed(optionsSearchWindow.java:8908)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mvap.optionsSearchWindow$optionsSearch
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 39 more
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the designated class is not found in the classpath.  This might be because you failed to put it there, or because it was afterward removed -- we have no basis on which to judge.  It might also be that the class isn't supposed to be there in the first place, and the one that tries to access it is in error -- perhaps it's an outdated version.  Try performing a clean build (and deploy the result if necessary).  Make sure there aren't any stale versions of your classes in the classpath.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this exception appeared after I deleted one of JButtons in my GUI, but that button didn't had any relation to this button that I am using right now and getting this exception.

Comment: Again: clean build.  If it succeeds then running the resulting (completely rebuilt) application should not produce such an error.  If the rebuild fails then the compiler's diagnostics will tell you what you need to fix.

Comment: Method `jButton2ActionPerformed()` of class `mvap.optionsSearchWindow` is trying to access its inner class `optionsSearch` which does not exist.